# Script finds all nine buttons but the ones at right go missing

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a sheet with nine transparent buttons at the top. The borders are opaque.
Columns A and B work as expected, but only one button (back) winds up in column C.
Version history helps to spot transparent buttons, so here's a screenshot.
[Version history shows all nine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6m0l.png)

I wrote a case for each button.

tab.getDrawings() finds all nine buttons, and placeDrawing highlights each target cell while adjusting that button's size and placement. Column C does get selected three times, but only row 2 seems to get a button. [Take a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Q5u7agpfySoLnzBReQ4vIEbT8ntp2C9Qh57c6nHrhI/edit#gid=1500251394) of the sheet to get the whole script:

```
function placeDrawings(e) {
    // Get active tab...
    switch (action) {
      case 'Totes':
        anchorRow = 1;
        anchorCol = 1;
        height = 24;
        width = 642;
        offsetX = 0;
        offsetY = 0;
        break;
        // ...times nine buttons
    }

    placeDrawing(drawing,
      anchorRow,
      anchorCol,
      height,
      width,
      offsetX,
      offsetY,
   )
}

function placeDrawing(drawing, r, c, x, y, h, w) {
  drawing
    .setPosition(r, c, x, y)
    .setHeight(h)
    .setWidth(w)
  drawing.getSheet()
    .getRange(r, c)
    .activateAsCurrentCell();
}
```

Comment: Resizing the target cells simplified placing buttons by hand. That fixed it, fwiw.